# ¿Como puedo hacer un contador de registros dentro de MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

****Soy nuevo en esta pagina**** 
buenas tardes lo que quiero saber es como hacer un contador de registro dentro de mvc este contador solo quiero que se ejecute cuando hago un registro en la vista de agregar mas que al momento que llegue a 10 se terminen los registros y que se pueda mostrar en la vista  los registros que llevamos pero no se me ocurre intente en la vista pero no me salio

------------------Controlador-----------

> mi get del controlador

```
        public ActionResult AgregarMas(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Reflector re = db.Reflectors.Find(id);
        if (re == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.IdTipo = new SelectList(db.TiposdeReflectores, "IdTipo", "TipodeReflector", re.IdTipo);
        ViewBag.IdTurno = new SelectList(db.TurnodelOperadors, "IdTurno", "IdTurno", re.IdTurno);
        return View(re);
    }
```

> puse aqui el contador pero no se si es necesario dentro del post de
>   create

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AgregarMas( Reflector reflector)
    {
```

> aqui esta mi contador

```
        int contador = 0;
        reflector.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //db.Entry(reflector).State = EntityState.Modified;
            //db.SaveChanges();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            db.Reflectors.Add(reflector);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

> Aqui tenia pensado hacer el conteo del controlador

```
            contador = contador + 1;
            return RedirectToAction("AgregarMas");



        }
        ViewBag.IdTipo = new SelectList(db.TiposdeReflectores, "IdTipo", "TipodeReflector", reflector.IdTipo);
        ViewBag.IdTurno = new SelectList(db.TurnodelOperadors, "IdTurno", "IdTurno", reflector.IdTurno);
        return View(reflector);
    }
```

---------------Vista--------------

```
@model Docuemto_de_reporte_de_excel.Models.Reflector
@using Docuemto_de_reporte_de_excel.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AgregarMas";
}

<h2>AgregarMas</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Reflector</h4>
    <hr />
    <hr />

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdTurno)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdTipo)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NumParte)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NumTO)

<dl class="form-group-lg">

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TiposdeReflectores)
        <span>:</span>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TiposdeReflectores.TipodeReflector)

    </dt>

</dl>
<dl class="form-control-lg">

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TurnodelOperador.Turno)
        <span>:</span>

        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TurnodelOperador.Turno)


    </dt>
</dl>
<dl class="form-control-lg">

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumParte)
        <span>:</span>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NumParte)

    </dt>

</dl>
<dl class="form-control-lg">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NumTO)
        <span>:</span>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NumTO)


    </dt>

</dl>


<hr />
<hr />

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Operador, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Operador, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Operador, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumSerie, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumSerie, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumSerie, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClaseRMS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClaseRMS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClaseRMS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RMSValor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RMSValor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RMSValor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValidaciondeRMS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidaciondeRMS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValidaciondeRMS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpacadoMPS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpacadoMPS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpacadoMPS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comentario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comentario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comentario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
```

> en el input de agregar se regresa al mismo metodo de agregar mas para
>   agregar registros

```
        <input type="submit" name="response" value="Agregar" id="agregar"formaction=@Url.Action("AgregarMas") formmethod="post" class="btn btn-default" />
```

```
</div>   

}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Con lo que tienes te da algún error? Supongo que siempre contador vale 0 ó 1. El problema es que siempre que se realiza una solicitud, la clase de tu controlador se vuelve a crear y eso "limpia" la variable. Podrías introducir contador dentro de tu modelo para actualizar su valor cada vez que se realiza un Registro.

Comment: no pero no me hace lo que quiero que haga @CarlosPozos

Comment: de hecho si tengo ese atributo  pero ahi no lo e usado

Comment: Utilizala en lugar de la variable "contador" y eso mantendrá una memoria de los Registros. En la acción AgregarMas que recibe un objeto Reflector, utiliza su propiedad, supongo que algo así como reflector.contador ++. Y antes de realizar algo, podrías validar que reflector.contador<10 y en caso contrario lo redirijes a una nueva ventana o le mandas un aviso, etc.

Comment: entonces seria dentro del httpost para poder ponder el registro @CarlosPozos